# Hacer resize en una aplicacion web de Javascript

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo una carrera de coches en JS, el coche debe ir de izquierda a derecha y eso va sin problemas. El asunto es que cuando empieza la carrera si hago una modificacion del tamaño de la ventana "resize" el coche llega hasta donde estaba la linea de meta, es decir, se detiene ahi y no continúa.

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que el coche continúe hasta que llegue a la linea indiferentemente donde esta esté?

Adjunto JS:

```
     var ordenLlegada = 0; // Variable global para el orden de llegada
    
      function acelera() {
        //Seleccionamos todos los coches en un array.
        var array = document.querySelectorAll(".coche"); 
        // hacemos una variable para medio la
        var largopista = $(window).width();
      
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
          var largoCoche = $(array[i]).width();
          var total = largopista - largoCoche;//con esto tenemos el problema de que si 
         movemos la pantalla el coche puede quedarse a medio camino o salirse
          var velocidad = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000) + 1);
      
          $(array[i]).animate({
            left: total
          }, velocidad, function() {
            // Función que se ejecuta al llegar al final de la pista
            ordenLlegada++; // Incrementar variable global de orden de llegada
            $(this).attr("data-orden-llegada", ordenLlegada); // Asignar orden de llegada 
            como atributo personalizado
            console.log("Coche " + $(this).attr("id") + " ha llegado en " + ordenLlegada + "º lugar");
          });
        }
      }
```

Comment: Lo que puedes hacer es dentro del **for** calcular la posición final de cada coche, así no importa si cambia el tamaño de la ventana o no.